# Is this an SMD Pulse transformer?

Tags: power-electronics, components, identification, datasheet, component-selection

I have two of these units. The one that looks fried actually worked just with some cleaning, and the other one won't power up. I check all the SMD Transistor and resistors and I am getting power to the unit. The fuse checked good. The only thing left is this that I thought it might be the pulse transformer since it seemed to have some winding underneath it.
On the pictures, the blue arrow points to the power plug or usb. The red arrow points to the unknown to me SMD component.
What is this component and does it do?
How do I verify if it's working fine?
Thank you

I can't post more than 2 links
[image]
The picture at the bottom you can see the winding kinda of. I couldn't take any better picture than that. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What made you think there would be  pulse transformer on the power pins?   The most sensible solution is a CM choke.  These are made to reduce noise on high impedance lines.

Comment: Are these known to fail if there is short circuit? Could it cause the board not to power up? Do I just test for continuity between the legs on sides?

Comment: yes, yes, maybe and isolation.